# Installing an apt package on the "live" (installer) environment

Tags: server, apt, package-management

Note: This is for a 16.04 Server image, so the standard live environment is not available.

I'm trying to access apt from the <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> extra shell in order to install the package required to make ATA Over Ethernet (AoE) targets visible to the system (in this case, `vblade`). The idea being, that I drop into a terminal, get the target disk visible, install onto it, drop back into the terminal and configure the installed system to load the proper modules on boot.

I understand that the image itself (booting from a USB drive) contains a number of apt packages, but apt itself does not appear to be in path in the install environment.

Also acceptable would be a way get get AoE working without the package, I suppose.

What would be the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original goal here was a wash, since the installer doesn't recognize drives added this way, but regarding the actual question here, getting important packages running in the install environment, the magic command is `udpkg`.

`udpkg` can be called with the `-i` option just like regular `dpkg` with the `.deb` files mounted at `/cdrom`. These packages are installed to the ramdrive install environment and go away when the system is rebooted.